# Wicket - Apache URL rewrite Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue

Tags: java, ajax, apache, url-rewriting, wicket

I'm facing a strange issue. I'm on UserPage on http://account.dev.pippo.com/account/UserPage in this page I have a DropDown component to filter a listview (using Ajax). 
When choosing a value from the dropdown the XMLHttpRequest is done against http://dev.pippo.com instead of http://account.dev.pippo.com/account. This leads to an Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://dev.pippo.com/wicket/page?3-1.IBehaviorListener.0-c…ontentList-layout-contentRight-overview-dateRange-listViewDateRangeOptions. Origin https://account.dev.pippo.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have an Apache rewrite rule that prepend the account. URL when /account is used.

The /account URL is mounted using:

```
mountPackage("/account", UserPage.class);
```

(I moved all panels and custom components used by this Page on the same package)

Should't wicket use the current URL (http://account.dev.pippo.com) as target for the Ajax request (to avoid browser blocking the requests)?

Why is this happening? Is this a wicket bug?

I'm using Apache Wicket 6.9.1.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
In the markup file I have the following AJAX request

```
Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"../wicket/page?3-1.IBehaviorListener.0-content-contentList-layout-contentRight-overview-dateRange-listViewDateRangeOptions","e":"change","c":"listViewDateRangeOptions13","ad":true,"m":"POST"});;
```

Comment: Wicket will render relative urls by default. Please check the url of your AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior in the resulting HTML markup, search in <script> tags for: Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"./choice?0-1.IBehaviorListener.0-form-makes","e":"change", ...)

Comment: Thanks Sven, see my EDIT, the problem is that the call is performed on /wicket/page (../) instead of /account/wicket/page (./) (and therefore not triggering the URL rewrite). How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to hint received through wicket mailing list there is a bug currently open which address this problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5043

The workaround suggested by Martin Grigorov, which works, is the following:

> Add:
>
> ```
> mountPage("/account/UserPage", UserPage.class);
> ```
>
> and check the produced markup. I'd expect to see something like:
>
> ```
> Wicket.Ajax.ajax({"u":"./?3-1.IBehaviorListener.0-content-contentList-layout-contentRight-overview-dateRange-listViewDateRangeOptions","e":"change","c":"listViewDateRangeOptions13","ad":true,"m":"POST"});;
> ```
>
> that is the url should not have "wicket/page" in front.